# Invoke JQuery function in webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, jquery

I am working on a project which has a WebBrowser Control i am trying to navigate to a web page that has a recaptcha check hidden and JQuery function to show the recaptcha with the name showRecaptchaFunction

```
function showRecaptchaFunction(element) {
    Recaptcha.create("_SiteKey", element, {
        theme: "red",
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    });
    $("#captcha_div").show().css({ visibility:'visible' });
}
```

when i am trying to call this function from WebBrowser with Document.InvokeScript method nothing happed and the recaptcha div didn't show.

```
 object script = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("showRecaptchaFunction", new object[] { "captcha_div" });
 if (script != null)
     MessageBox.Show(script.ToString());
```

I can't find the way to call this function so when the webpage completed i call the function to show the recaptcha div, in addition to that i can't change the webpage script to show the recaptcha when the webpage ready.

> To clarify, I have a web control component in windows forms that is
>   loading a third party browser in which i would like to invoke a
>   javascript function that exists on that web-site.

Comment: To clarify, you have a web control component in windows forms that is loading a third party browser in which you would like to invoke a javascript function that exists on that web-site?

Comment: @Greg, ya that's right.

Comment: Any body can help me.

Comment: I'd have to think the problem though, but I assume your server is invoking the script before the Dom is ready.  So the script doesn't exists at that moment.

Comment: but the recaptcha dosn't shown until a response of the sever that you need to verify you are human and this happens after the Dom is ready